# Change proxy in new tab undetected_chromedriver (selenium)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'd like to open a new tab in my browser via undetected_chromedriver and change proxy at the same time, but I don't know how to do it or if it's possible.

Why do I want to do this? Because when I scrap via selenium sometimes I get blocked by the website and I want to use a new proxy without closing the selenium instance and opening a new one with a new proxy.

For the moment here is my code without my attempts with a new proxy because it does not work

```
from undetected_chromedriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import requests
import sys
import time
import os

# créer des options pour Chrome

proxies = {'http': 'My_proxy', 'https': 'My_proxy'}



options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--disable-browser-side-navigation')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxies["http"]}')
options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxies["https"]}')

options.headless = False


# créer une instance de Chrome en utilisant Undetected Chromedriver
driver = Chrome(options=options)






# ouvrir la page web souhaitée
#driver.get("http://nowsecure.nl")




driver.execute_script('''window.open("http://google.com","_blank");''')  # open page in new tab

time.sleep((3))
driver.switch_to.window(window_name=driver.window_handles[0])  # switch to first tab
driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(window_name=driver.window_handles[0])  # switch to first tab
time.sleep((3))
```

Thank you for your help